# Python pip - could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/package

Tags: python, pip

when I try to install package in virtualenv using pip 1.5.4, I get this error (for example when i want to install six):

```
Downloading/unpacking six
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/six/: connection error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/six/ when looking for download links for six
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: connection error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for six
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/six/: connection error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/six/ when looking for download links for six
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement six
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /var/www/sova/venv/build...
No distributions at all found for six
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/sova/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/var/www/sova/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/var/www/sova/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1177, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/var/www/sova/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 277, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for six

Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

when I try easy_install, I get SSL error (I was getting this to with pip, but I solved it). And packages obviously exists... I don't use proxy - this PC is connected by ethernet directly to router with static IP. Same configuration work on other PC (also static IP, same router). My connection works fine - I can update my system, ping google etc.

Thank you